# Optional -SkipDuplicate doesn't work when nuget push, what's wrong?

Tags: gitlab, nuget

when I run a command to send a nupkg package to the `Package Registry` in myGitLab CE , i using the command `nuget push "*.nupkg" -Source GitLab_packages -SkipDuplicate`

I get a message about a successful completion, but shouldn’t have downloaded the package because there’s already one,but...

```
 PS C:\_soft\devnupkg> nuget push "*.nupkg" -Source GitLab_packages -skipduplicate
Pushing anglesharp.0.17.1.nupkg to 'https://gitlab.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/149/packages/nuget'...
  PUT https://gitlab.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/149/packages/nuget/
  Created https://gitlab.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/149/packages/nuget/ 716ms
Your package was pushed.
```

In  `help` command `nuget push /help` set: `-SkipDuplicate                                                  If a package and version already exists, skip it and continue with the next package in the push, if any.`

What's i do wrong?
THK

Answer (score 1):

SkipDuplicate relies on a 409 response from the source. It is very possible that the source is not returning 409 in that case and just overwriting.
You can use fiddler or some other tool to check the HTTP resposne, but it is extremely likely that overwrite is just the server behavior.

Have you tried pushing without a -SkipDuplicate? If the package gets override then this is just the server behavior.